# Ubuntu 14.04 won't recognize Garmin etrex 30 GPS

Tags: 14.04, usb, gps

I'm traveling Europe by bike with a Garmin Etrex 30 gps. I'd like to use Viking or Foxtrot GPS for mapping purposes. Problem is, my computer, an Asus 1050HA eeepc, won't recognize my GPS device. When I usb plug in the gps it says it's saving the data as .gpx files. But i can't find the device, or the files, on the system.

Any help appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

While you might do some work with `Viking` reviewing `.gpx` files for transfer to and from the **Etrex 30**, you will not get it to work with FoxtrotGPS as a live gps device.

It doesn't have the ability to stream data, and FoxtrotGPS uses [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) to stream the data to itself.

I think it might be the wrong device for what you might be wanting to do.

If, and why, it is not recognised as a mass storage device is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Garmin told me:

> "Thank you for contacting Garmin International. I'm happy to help with
>   your question concerning the Garmin Communicator Plugin.
>
> Unfortunately, the plugin is not compatible with a Linux OS. It will
>   work with Windows XP or later and Mac OSX 10.6 or later.
>
> You can respond directly to this email with any further questions you
>   might have, or you can call us Monday through Thursday 8am to 6pm CST,
>   or Friday 8am to 5pm CST. The toll free customer service number is
>   1-800-800-1020.
>
> With Best Regards,
>
> Karen 6887 Customer Care - Outdoor Team Garmin International"

Although there may be a way to work around it